# Displaying Users in AAD Group Graph API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I know this is simple but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I'm trying to load a list of users from an Azure AD Group using the graph api. I'm almost there. I can successfully call the API, get the right group, and even see the members.  But when I load that list in a list, all i see is a list of Microsoft.Graph.User.  If inspect the list in code, I can drill down and see the display names but I don't know how to access them via code.  there is no .displayname within the user object.  Below is the code I have:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = await Authentication.SignInAndInitGraph(scope);
List<User> users = new List<User>();

var members = await graphClient.Groups["GroupID"].Members
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();

users.AddRange(members.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());

while(members.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
      members = await members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
      users.AddRange(members.CurrentPage.OfType<User>());
    }

lstUsers.DataSource = users;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the type of lstUsers? Do you have desktop app or web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert members to list.

```
var members = await graphClient.Groups["group_id"].Members.Request().GetAsync();
var list = members.ToList();
foreach (Microsoft.Graph.User user in list) {
    var name = user.DisplayName;
}
```

[image]